# Why does Google not index the subpages, even when manually added?

Tags: seo, google-search

Since about 2 months, we have updated our website with a directory of coaches which can be found on multiple search templates such as http://www.sollicitatiedokter.nl/coaching .

We've created (multiple) sitemaps, sitemap pages, added /coaching/ to Google Webmaster Tools requested it to be crawled and with it the links on this page. Today I even added http://www.sollicitatiedokter.nl/coaching-index/ and let google crawl it + submitting it to index, but only this page was indexed, not the links on the page.

I even tried adding the subpages individually to Webmaster Tools but still Google refuses to show them in the search results. I've submitted them 7/25/14, nearly 10 days ago. However Google states that it takes up to 10 minutes to crawl a request through this service.

I've checked the http request codes which are all OK 200, robots.txt is not blocking them and all links do not contain a nofollow of any kind. I am pretty much out of reasons in why Google refuses to index these pages. I hope someone on SO has any idea/advice.

Comment: When did you submit your subpages?

Comment: I've submitted them 7/25/14, nearly 10 days ago. However Google states that it takes up to 10 minutes to crawl a request through this service.

Comment: Do they promise they are going to crawl in 10 mins. Can you share a link please ? I am not sure about that. By the way, when did your site last indexed by the spider? I am sure you will need to allow more time see the change happen.

Comment: See this image: https://imageshack.com/i/exrnMwuHj

Also I just added an extra page and it is already indexed, so it does seem to be processed within this timeframe.

https://www.google.com/search?q=sollicitatiedokter+crawlingtest&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&gws_rd=ssl#q=site:sollicitatiedokter.nl+crawlingtest%2F&safe=off

Comment: Yes indeed it says it processes shortly. But it does not conclude that it will include it in the listings (google search resutls). My advice is to check for another couple of days, a week maximum. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect canoncial tags which refer back to `<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.sollicitatiedokter.nl/coach/' />`

Comment: Yes! That was it, its indexing properly now. Thanks! I'm not familar with canonical links, but I guess I learned the hard way.